# Postgresql: Function with temporary tables

Tags: database, function, postgresql, temp-tables

I have a function which accesses temporary tables. I can create this function in a session and drop the function once application exit the session. But I do not want to recreate the function in every session.

Will the function remain valid if I do not recreate in each session?

Comment: Well...Have you tried not recreating it?

Comment: No, I have not. But in my code I am unable to reach to this point, so I could not try it yet. So in the meantime, I thought to get some concrete information on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function validity checking in run time. You don't need to drop your function.